# Programação PHP WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress

Eu comprei um tema wordpress, ele quando fui comprar aparece todo bonitão.

O problema é que quando instalo ele só aparece postagens!

O que eu faço ?
Quero ele bonitão como comprei.

Comment: Ele só aparece postagens? Como é um tema comprado, o ideal é entrar em contato com desenvolvedor e perguntar se ele não pode te enviar a mesma config da demo.

Comment: Qual é a programação aclamada no título da pergunta?

Comment: Onde eu consigo contato? se eu conseguisse a config onde colocaria?

Comment: Você pode entrar em contato através do site no qual comprou o tema. Caso tenha sido no ThemeForest, basta acessar https://themeforest.net/downloads e depois em "Premium E-mail"

Comment: Jessica vc tem que instalar o Tema da forma correta. junto com os Plugins e o "Semple Data". Que é a forma que vc vê o Template no demo do Site onde comprou. Aqui tem um vídeo que pode te ajudar. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubJXGLd3EEo ou então procure no Youtube / Google como Instalar o Sample Data do Tema Wordpress

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta na sua outra pergunta (copia): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263549/configura%c3%a7%c3%a3o-tema-wordpress/263583#263583

Answer (score -1):

Para ele ficar igual ao tema de exemplo da loja, você deve importar as Configurações e o Demo Content do tema.

Essa é a tela de importação do meu tema (Oxides).
Você deve procurar nas configurações do seu tema.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]